# Appcelerator failed to install apk on Android device, because of keystone certificate

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

For an app I'm working on, I made a custom keystore certificate to test with. No problems, using it now for about a 3 weeks.
But now, just like that, when trying to run it on my Android device, Appcelerator suddenly says: [ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "TA34801BY7" ...

When I remove the keystore reference in my Run Configuration, so the app uses a default generated certificate, the app installs ... so, there's a keystone problem, but why? and how do I solve it? I really need to use my custom made certificate.

Comment: Problem solved ... after resetting my phone a couple of times, it starts installing again.
It would be nice to have some more information from Appcelerator, more than 'Failed to install' ... it took me hours discovering that the certificate was the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: This error message may be coming from adb, and not Appc.  I've seen this when I had installed an unsigned app on a device, then later tried to install a signed version.